# Is it possible to add to different aliases to the same table in a dynamic query?

Tags: database

I would like to use a example query for retrieving a full tree of the nested set model in a dynamic query.

```
SELECT node.name
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND parent.name = 'ELECTRONICS'
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

The problem is that dynamic queries can't alias the same table. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: the question is whether a dynamic query would be a good fit for the situation, most probably a static query would be enough ? Even the [official doc](http://drupal.org/node/310075) is surprisingly discouraging regarding to dynamic queries ...

Comment: and BTW: i love the nested set idea :) i havent seen it used in drupal yet ... is this some public stuff ?

Comment: The nested set modal also know as the modified preorder tree traversal algorithm has a good explanation found on [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). It has some benefits over the adjacent tree model which is used in Drupal Taxonomy for maintaining term hierarchies because it can pull a tree with a single query  while the adjacent tree model requires less resources to update. See the Drupal leftandright module and the Drupal lineage module

Comment: @mojzis why would a static query be enough ? If he wants other modules to be able to alter this query such as changing the value passed to `parent.name` ... or add other `Joins` ... then that's what dynamic queries are for. Dynamic queries are easier to build APIs with, or allow flexability in a library.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have at this point is to simply execute the subquery first using fetchAssoc() to return an array.

```
$subquery = db_select('nested_category', 'parent');
$subquery->addField('parent', 'lft');
$subquery->addField('parent', 'rgt');
$subquery->condition('name', $name, '=');
$parent = $subquery->execute()->fetchAssoc();

$query = db_select('nested_category', 'node');
$query->addField('node', 'name');
$query->condition('node.lft',$parent, 'BETWEEN');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```